# Is it possible to get a component from layout in Vaadin by labeling it?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a question. Is it possible to get a component from a layout in Vaadin by labeling it with a specific name or something?

Asume that we have this code.

```
    NumberField totalSamples = new NumberField();
    totalSamples.setValue(0d);
    totalSamples.setEnabled(false);
    Label label = new Label("Total samples:");
    Button start = new Button("Start");
    row = new HorizontalLayout();
    row.add(start, label, totalSamples);
    layout.add(row);
```

If I want to get the `label` object from `layout` and first need to get the `row` object and if I don't know the index of all of them. Is there some way to get these objects by setting a specific number or name to them?

```
    Button start = layout.getComponentAt(index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a collection.

Vaadin objects are simply Java objects. So, as you instantiate the widgets, add them to a `List` or other collection that fits your needs.

Your collection can be stored as a member variable on your outer layout class.

In your specific case of needing to track dynamically-created rows where each has three widgets across, create a class. That class should extend `HorizontalLayout`. The class would have three member variables, each named so you can later access them individually.

```
class Row extends HorizontalLayout {

    NumberField totalSamples ;
    Label label ;
    Button start ;

    // Constructor
    public Row ( … ) {
        totalSamples = … ;
        label = … ;
        start = … ;
        this.add( label , totalSamples , start ) ;
    }

}
```

You could add other member variables to this `Row` class besides Vaadin widgets. If each row represents a particular product made by your company, the add a `productId` field. Or perhaps you you want to track each row individually for logging, debugging, or audit trail. If so, add a `UUID` field to the class.

That `Row` class could be nested within the outer layout class, as you’ll not need it anywhere else in your app.

On your outer layout, instantiate, collect, and place the rows.